# how to identify the ring $R$ of power series of the form $f_i(x,y)=(g_i(x),h_i(y))$?

Tags: ring-theory, power-series

Let us define $f_i(x,y)=(g_i(x),h_i(y))$, where $g_i(x) \in \mathbb Z[[x]]$ and $h_i(y) \in \mathbb Z[[y]]$ are power series, $i \in \mathbb N$.

We can think of $f_i(x,y)$ as an element of $ \mathbb Z[[x]] \times \mathbb Z[[y]]$.

The set of all $f_i(x,y)$ forms a ring $R$, say.

> What is the ring $R$ ? Is it a subring of $\mathbb Z[[x]] \times \mathbb Z[[y]]$ or $\mathbb Z[[x]] \oplus \mathbb Z[[y]]$ ?

---

I think $R$ can not be direct sum $\mathbb Z[[x]] \oplus \mathbb Z[[y]]$ because direct sum of two rings is not defined.

So how to identify the ring $R$ ?

Comment: What is the subscript $i$ doing? Does the definition just mean that $f$ consists of an ordered pair $(g, h)$ where $g \in \mathbb{Z}[[x]], h \in \mathbb{Z}[[y]]$? If so, haven't you just defined the cartesian product?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, I used the subscript $i$ to mean the collection of all $f_i$, but we can ignore it. Yes, I am defining $f$ as a vector valued map from $\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$. Yes I should have defined it as cartesian product.

Comment: There are uncountably many choices for $g$ and $h$... in any case, if the addition and multiplication are pointwise you've just defined the cartesian product. What is the mystery here?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, i think this was the mystery and you exposed it. I just wanted to define a new ring out of two power series ring. But I was confused because of direct sum which is not defined for two rings. Thanks I got it